# Stage3D porting GLSL to AGAL

Tags: actionscript-3, shader, vertex-shader, stage3d, agal

I am trying to port this GLSL Shaders to Stage3D and AGAL, but I cannot make it work:

Vertex Shader (GLSL)

```
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec4 aVertexColor;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

    varying vec4 vColor;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        vColor = aVertexColor;
    }
```

Fragment Shader (GLSL)

```
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec4 vColor;

    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = vColor;
    }
```

Having as a result:

Vertex Shader (AGAL)

```
mov vt0.w, vc0.x
mov vt0.xyz, va0.xyz

mov vt1.xyzw, vc1
mul vt5.xyzw, vt1, vc5
m44 op.xyzw, vt0.xyzw, vt5
mov v0.xyzw, va1.xyzw
```

Fragment Shader (AGAL)

```
mov oc.xyzw, v0.xyzw
```

Here it is a trace of the instructions I execute:

```
(setVertexBufferAt) va0 3 0
(setVertexBufferAt) va1 4 3
(identity setProgramConstantsFromMatrix): vc0 1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1
(setProgramConstantsFromMatrix) vc1 1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-2,1
(setProgramConstantsFromMatrix) vc5 1.8106601238250732,0,0,0,0,2.4142136573791504,0,0,0,0,-1.0020020008087158,-1,0,0,-0.20020020008087158,0
render drawTriangles + present
```

But I can't still see anything.

**Update:
Apparently the problem is that the triangle is being clipped. Values on the multiplicated array are bigger than 1.0 which makes them clipped out. So I need to find a way to normalize the matrix or yo extend the clipping**

Any suggestion?

Comment: Two thoughts: 1. What would happen if you removed the ".xyzw" from register access of the matrices? 2. There is no z component in va0. It looks like it only has an x and a y (based on your trace). Is this correct?

Comment: @bwroga I just found one of the possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

Digging up an old post here, but for the sake of any future searches you should really check out:

https://github.com/adobe/glsl2agal

It works pretty much as you would hope - takes valid glsl vertex/fragment shader programs as input, spits out valid agal as output.

as an example:
http://www.cmodule.org/glsl2agal/